# Joining a game with an empty slot

Tags: simcity-2013

I would like to join a game, but each slot I click on, I see every city has a major. I was getting tired clicking in and seeing all were taken. It was not helped by seeing the blue default avatar that looks like an empty slot but is really a player without a picture.

What do I look for so I can join a game with an available city I can govern?

Comment: You need to filter the games that have empty slots.  Are you aware of how to tell if a lot hasn't been claimed yet?

Comment: When I made the comment I was under the impression the filter were still enabled.  Of course in a month my comment will make more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. There should be filters in the join dialog, allowing you to see regions with empty slots or a specific map, but those were removed in an effort to reduce server stress. I haven't seen any statement as to when they will return.

Like with most other games, I've come to rely on other communities to find players rather than using the in-game browser. So here is what you do:

Go to [/r/SimCity](http://www.reddit.com/r/SimCity/) and make a post stating youre creating a region and looking for players. I found four players within the hour. The [#SimCity](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23simcity) tag also contains regular tweets from players looking for a game.

Answer (score 1):

*As mizipor states; they have removed the search controls from the screen.*

The best way I have determined, is to click on the city log, which is found on the bottom left side. It announces "come play with [username]". Clicking on the log will show you the map where if there is a city available, you can join in.

I clicked on a couple of entries and found found maps with cities abandoned/available. This seems to be the best way to join games with others.

Answer (score 1):

While the search controls are off, you have to find an alternate path.  Here's a way to join games with people you've never met.

1. Use the City Log to find active players, go to a region from here.  That region is probably full.
2. Click on a city, and then the mayor to go to that mayor's profile page.
3. Join a region which is not full from that mayor's profile page.