# How do I filter out regions that are full?

Tags: simcity-2013

Does anyone know if it is possible to filter out regions that are full when looking for a region to join?  I have looked on the North American servers and I am having trouble finding a region that is not actually full.  I've created cities on my own public regions already but no one is joining, so I figured I'd try to see if I could join someone else's public region.  What I am finding is that all the regions that the game gives me are already full.

Comment: DUP: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108028/joining-a-game-with-an-empty-slot?noredirect=1#comment145454_108028